# More Natural Wrapping/Floating

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, word-wrap

I'm trying to build a very basic thumbnail gallery. When you click on a thumbnail, it expands to be one of three sizes (square, vertical or horizontal).
The problem I'm having is that when it expands, the pictures want to stay in the same order, instead of filling in the empty blocks with thumbnails. Obviously, what's written first shows up first - and that normally makes sense. I'm wondering if there's a way to make the images pop out from the stream and act like blocks with textwrap work in InDesign.
Here's what I have so far: http://fiendconsulting.com/uglyduck_testing/toggle_test.html
Any ideas?

I'm not that great at this and I'm out of practice with any kind of programming the last few months, so take it easy and keep it simple please. Thanks in advance. -T

Comment: I don't know exactly how textwrap works in InDesign, but can't you keep the original image in the flow in the original size, and show the larger image in a new container that is positioned over the gallery?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing that. It makes it too hard to look at things really fast: click to open the image bigger, click to close it so you can look at the thumbnails again; and it means that you can't really see more than one big picture at a time.<br>

Comment: You need to give the thumbnail items  a css value of `position: absolute;`

Comment: I'd like the picture to open up from their top left corner if they're on the left side, from the top right if they're on the right side, and scootch the thumbnails in their new area off to the sides/below, without leaving any gaps.

Comment: Can I get the thumbs to automatically wrap around the bigger images if they're positioned absolutely? If so, please let me know how. That would make my life SO much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think the masonry jquery plugin will do what you want. An example of how what I think you're looking for works is this:

http://www.swiftkey.net/en/our-company/#team

They do this using a jquery plugin called isotope (which is a more complete version of masonry you pay for). It also requires some advanced-ish type jquery skills for handling callbacks and what not.

The principle behind what they do is hide the larger content then when you click on a portrait you hide the smaller image and show the larger image, then re-layout the masonry grid. You should be able to play with it and get some really nice functionality out of it. Its pretty en vogue atm.